# A question being closed hides the possible duplicate comment

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I voted to close a question for being a duplicate, then edited the automatic comment for clarification in case the OP does not see how it is a duplicate.

Subsequently the question was closed, hiding my comment (and explanation).

I see the point of this behavior but if this is the case what should I do if I feel further explanation is warranted? Edit the comment for it to be lost later, or make two comments in a row? The idea of intentionally double commenting makes me cringe but that doesn't mean it's unacceptable behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auto-generated comment is removed by design. There's no need to repeat the close notice in the comment as it's added to the top of the post.

If you think you need to add more details then add a new comment.

Comment: So you don't see any issue with intentionally leaving two comments in a row?

Comment: @Fr33dan - no, especially as one of them is likely to be removed.

Comment: If this is the desired behavior perhaps the comment shouldn't be editable in the first place. I feel a feature request coming on.

Comment: @Fr33dan - in the vast majority of cases the comment won't be edited. Is it really necessary to have a feature request for the 0.1% of cases where you (and I do mean the specific you here) want to add more information?

Comment: I don't see any problem with making the request. I could certainly see it not being implemented for being too specific but that's no reason to not bring it up for discussion.